# tkinter window appearing with nothing

Tags: python, tkinter

I am fairly confused why this code fails to produce anything in a window. The labels, text entries, and button have all been created within the class. Their master frame is root which is passed through **init**. I know this is a super trivial question, but it's very similar to what is in the book I'm reading, but the book is 14 years old. Can anyone explain to me what I have overlooked?

```
from tkinter import *
import hashlib

class Login:

    def __init__(self, master):

        ##Set frame as root window
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        Label(top, text="Username").pack()

        ##Enter Username
        self.username = Entry(frame)
        self.username.pack()
        self.username.set_focus() #keyboard entry starts here

        Label(top, text="Password").pack()

        ##Enter Password
        self.password = Entry(frame)
        self.password.pack()

        ##Login
        self.login = Button(frame, text="Login", width=10)
        self.login.pack()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("400X400+300+300")
    app = Login(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: What's "top" in `Label(top, text="Username").pack()`.  Are you missing some code here?

Comment: That's supposed to be "frame". I switched it, but it made no difference, nothing showed up in the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tested this under Python 2, and had to fix four things:

1. Change `tkinter` to `Tkinter` (Python 3 uses `tkinter`, though, so I assume that's what you're using)
2. Fix the geometry string (use lowercase x) to avoid `TclError: bad geometry specifier`.
3. Change `top` to `frame`, to avoid a `NameError`.
4. Change `set_focus` to `focus_set`, to avoid an `AttributeError`.

With these changes in place, the script works as expected.

(and I just confirmed that it works under Python 3 as well, if I skip the first change)

Are you running this under some IDE that doesn't show you the exceptions?

Comment: I had two instances open by accident. The "top" was the cause. I had assumed that if a window came up then no errors had occurred, but after I posted I noticed the syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

you are using root when you create the instance of the class but top in the class;

here is what i did for it to work:

```
from Tkinter import *
import hashlib

class Login:

    def __init__(self, master):

        ##Set frame as root window
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()


        Label(frame, text="Username").pack()

        ##Enter Username
        self.username = Entry(frame)
        self.username.pack()


        Label(frame, text="Password").pack()

        ##Enter Password
        self.password = Entry(frame)
        self.password.pack()

        ##Login
        self.login = Button(frame, text="Login", width=10)
        self.login.pack()

def main():
    root = Tk()

    app = Login(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```